# adding char[] to char** (string to a list of strings)

Tags: c, string, pointers

The program should create strings depending on input. we want to add these strings to a list, which is passed to the function as a pointer (to other char * pointers).
the code looks like this:

```java
void main(void) {
    //set angles alpha (small) & beta (large)
    char ** configurations = calloc(0, sizeof(char*));
    int multiplicity = 0;

    createConfigString(4, 4, 0, configurations, 0, &multiplicity);
}

void createConfigString(int a, int b, int c, char ** configurations, int start, int * multiplicity) {
int x, i;
int strSize = 2 * (a + b + c);

for(x = a; x >= (a + (a % 2)) / 2; x--) {
    //new entry to configurations if starting a new line
    if(start == 0) {
        configurations = realloc(configurations, (*multiplicity + 1) * sizeof(char *));
        configurations[*multiplicity] = calloc(strSize, sizeof(char));
    }
    for(i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        configurations[*multiplicity][start] = "a,";
    }
    if(b == 2) {
        *multiplicity++;
        configurations[*multiplicity][start + 2 * x] = "b,b\n";
        start = 0;
        continue;
    }
    configurations[*multiplicity][start + 2 * x] = "b,b,";
    createConfigString(a - x, b - 2, c, configurations, start + 2 * x + 4, multiplicity);
}
}
```

but at compile it tells us it's trying to cast pointer into int on the lines

```java
configurations[*multiplicity][start] = "a,";
configurations[*multiplicity][start + 2 * x] = "b,b\n";
configurations[*multiplicity][start + 2 * x] = "b,b,";
```

when we write

```java
configurations[*multiplicity][start] = (int) "a,";
```

etc. it does compile without any warning

what are we doing wrong? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, since `configurations` is a `char **`, then `configurations[n]` is a `char *`, and `configurations[n][m]` is then expected to be a `char`. You are attempting to assign a `char *` to a `char`, and in order to do that, the compiler has to convert the pointer to an integral type, which will then get truncated down to `char` size. This is generally not at all what the coder wants, so it generates the warning to let you know you're probably doing something wrong. Putting the cast in tells the compiler "yes, I really want to do this, so don't warn me". However, it probably still doesn't do what you are thinking it does...

Also, this:

```
char ** configurations = calloc(0, sizeof(char*));
```

is potentially problematic. The man page for `calloc` on Linux has this to say:

```
If nmemb or size is 0, then calloc() returns either NULL, or
a unique pointer value that can later be successfully passed to free().
```

Since you don't check the return value, you are potentially passing a NULL pointer into `createConfigString`. Perhaps your current platform actually returns a "usable" value, but it's not going to be portable. In the case it does return a NULL, it's possible that the later `realloc` may have problems (although on Linux, it seems it would be ok), which you also don't check for...

Comment: I'm really a C noob, so this explanation is really helpful. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can't copy strings using `=`, you have to use a function - such as the standard `strcpy` function.

So:

```
    configurations[*multiplicity][start] = "a,";
```

should be:

```
    strcpy(configurations[*multiplicity][start], "a,");
```

And the same type of patterns elsewhere.

Comment: thanks! note that strcpy requires a pointer though, so it should be strcpy(&configurations[*multiplicity][start], "str") does this mean that when i use

    '= "example str"'

"example str" would be read as a pointer?

Comment: Anywhere you want characters to "move" from one place to another.